# iOS animating a view including subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview

I'm trying to make an animation for collapsing a view which includes some subviews.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"advancedAnimations" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];

CGRect aFrame = aView.frame;
aView.size.height = 0;
aView.frame = aFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This animation is doing fine, but for the aView only. Subviews doesn't collapse as expected.
How do I make the subviews collapsing as well? Furthermore, is there a way to recalculate original size after collapsing?

THX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to apply some autoresizing mask to your subviews. If you do

```
for (UIView *subview in aView.subviews) {
    subview.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
}
```

it should work.

BUT,
personally I would use, as lamelas said

```
aView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,0.0);
```

Comment: Still good, but the thing I want to do is to collapse the view, hiding its content as it gets smaller. CGAffineTransformMakeScale scales the whole content. BTW, you can't use 0.0 in transformations.

Comment: Where did you see that we can't use 0.0 in transforms ? Anyway, I'm not sure what your question is… Do you want your subviews to scale to, or you want them to be cropped as the animation occurs ?

Comment: Try to set it to 0.0 and look what is animation will look like and compare it to setting to 0.001. I am tying not to resize the subviews, but to have a "slide door" effect, as the main view gets smaller.

Comment: Ok, so you just have to set the property clipToBounds of your main view to YES then.

Comment: Regarding setting a zero value in transforms (CGAffine + CA3D ones), iOS 6+ seems to let it slide and will animate appropriately. The ".001" trick is the way to go though for compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this to animate:

```
aView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,0.0);
```

Comment: Works better, but the animation is a bit strange - tries to "squeeze" the view into the middle point.

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"advancedAnimations" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];

CGRect aFrame = aView.frame;
aView.size.height = 0;
aView.frame = aFrame;

for (UIView *subview in aView.subviews) {
    CGRect frame = subview.frame;
    frame.size.height = 0;
    subview.frame = frame;
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

> Furthermore, is there a way to recalculate original size after collapsing?

You'll probably want to just save the height before collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift syntax for setting `autoresizingMask` is slightly different than ObjC:

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    subview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
}
```